# why doesn't this function return a value?

Tags: javascript

Learning javascript, I am trying understand why the following function doesn't return true or false. When I step through the code with debugger I see that it steps into either `return true` or `return false` case.

```
doesNumExistInArray = (objArray, num) => {
    Object.keys(objArray).forEach(key => {
      if (objArray[key].number === parseInt(num)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  };
```

But calling `isDuplicate = doesNumExistInArray(objects, num)` always assigns `isDuplicate` undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: `doesNumExistInArray` doesn't have a `return` statement

Comment: Good point @Quentin, +1. I left a more detailed answer showing OP how to use `.map` and `.reduce` to get the output they wanted. Would be welcome to any notes you have.

Comment: Your inner `forEach`function returns a boolean, but your outer `doesNumExistInArray` does not return anything. Besides, your code won't work even if it returned something.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Array.prototype.some`.

If at any point, there is a match, the function will return true.

The `Array.prototype.forEach` method returns `undefined`, so this will not work as a returable function.

```js
doesNumExistInArray = (objArray, num) => {
  return Object.keys(objArray).some(key => {
    return objArray[key].number === parseInt(num);
  });
};
```

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote. I'm actually shocked by browser support for `Array.some`, [93.7%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_array_some). This is probably better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`doesNumExistInArray` is a function, but it does not return anything. It actually runs, with `Array.forEach`, what's called an "anonymous function" that loops over the keys in `objArray`.

Basically, `Array.forEach` *does* something for each element and returns nothing (like a `void` in other languages), where `Array.map` returns some modified version of the original array. Let's use `Array.map` to turn the array into a list of Booleans denoting whether or not the `objArray` key is equal to the number given as an argument (will look like `[true, false, false]` for input `1`), then use `Array.reduce` to sum the booleans where `true => 1` and `false => 0`. Basically, summing a list of booleans will give you the number of true values - if that number is not zero, we found a match.

That might seem really complicated, but this algorithm would work in Python and other frameworks where you want to check if there's at least one `true` value in a list of booleans.

```js
doesNumExistInArray = (objArray, num) => Object.keys(objArray).map(
    key => objArray[key].number === parseInt(num)
  ).reduce((a,b) => a + b) > 0;

var objArray = [
  {
    number: 1,
  },
  {
    number: 2,
  },
  {
    number: 3
  }
];

console.log("doesNumExistInArray(objArray, 1) =>", doesNumExistInArray(objArray, 1));
console.log("doesNumExistInArray(objArray, 5) =>", doesNumExistInArray(objArray, 5));

// see that Array.forEach returns undefined
console.log("[1,2,3].forEach((x) => x * 2)=>\n", [1,2,3].forEach((x) => x * 2))

// whereas Array.map returns callback output
console.log("[1,2,3].map((x) => x * 2)=>\n", [1,2,3].map((x) => x * 2))
```